# Traverse some methods to main "call handling" activity

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I'm curious if there is a possibility to traverse some methods from my application to the main call handling app.
For example if the phone is called, to show a different activity with a "Response" button and if the user presses it, to send this message to the main call handling activity on the device.

I know how to show an activity before the main call handling activity via `BroadcastReceiver`, but this type of actions is way less trivial than that.

So here's my list of questions:

- Is it possible to send messages to the call handling app on the device, after I catch the phone state ..RINGING?
- If yes (look up), will this app feature be recognized by the Play Store as non-viral (Of course the user will be notified that this app has such a feature)?
- And if both answer are yes to the previous two, where should I start my research regarding this topic (are there any tutorials or blogs that describe same/like mechanisms)?

Any help will be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious if there is a possibility to traverse some methods from my application to the main call handling app.

No, because the "main call handling app" is not your app, and is not in your process.

> Is it possible to send messages to the call handling app on the device, after I catch the phone state ..RINGING?

There is no documented or supported means of sending "messages to the call handling app".

You are welcome to create your own ROM mod with your own revised version of the "call handling app" to do what you want, then convince people to run that ROM mod.

Comment: Thx, you saved me a lot of time and nerves... By the way I like your book very much, learned a lot cool stuff from it...